# How to sort a list of lists by a specific index of the inner list?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of lists.  For example,

```
[
[0,1,'f'],
[4,2,'t'],
[9,4,'afsd']
]
```

If I wanted to sort the outer list by the string field of the inner lists, how would you do that in python?

Comment: Link to tutorial: http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/

Comment: useful link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142090/python-sort-a-list-of-lists-by-an-item-in-the-sublist

Answer (score 399, accepted):

This is a job for [itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> L=[[0, 1, 'f'], [4, 2, 't'], [9, 4, 'afsd']]
>>> sorted(L, key=itemgetter(2))
[[9, 4, 'afsd'], [0, 1, 'f'], [4, 2, 't']]
```

It is also possible to use a lambda function here, however the lambda function is slower in this simple case

Comment: What if I would want to ignore case?

Comment: @bzupnick, use `key=lambda x:x[2].casefold()`. If your Python isn't new enough, just use `.lower()` instead of `.casefold()`

Comment: x = [[[5,3],1.0345],[[5,6],5.098],[[5,4],4.89],[[5,1],5.97]] With a list like this is can we sort using itemgetter() with respect to elements in x[0][1] ?

Comment: Can I also get the indices of the sort, so to sort another related list of lists in the same order?

Comment: @quaryk It sounds like an interesting question, but not suitable to answer in the comments. If you can't find a question that covers it, you should create one.

Comment: Is a `lambda` function really slower ? In the source code, `itemgetter` seems to work the same way...

Comment: @AxelPuig, it's not hard to check. I get 772ns for the itemgetter and 849ns for a lambda function. The relative difference seems to get worse for the `lambda` as `L` gets longer

Comment: I was using a `lambda` solution until I learned `itemgetter()` is faster.

Answer (score 256):

in place

```
>>> l = [[0, 1, 'f'], [4, 2, 't'], [9, 4, 'afsd']]
>>> l.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])
```

not in place using sorted:

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[2])
```

Comment: Could you give more details about `in place` and `not in place` ?

Comment: @qun, "in place" means that the memory of the old list is reused for the sorted one. "not in place" means that the old list remains unchanged and a new list is created.

Comment: x = [[[5,3],1.0345],[[5,6],5.098],[[5,4],4.89],[[5,1],5.97]] With a list like this is, how can we sort with respect to elements in x[0][1] ?

Comment: for descending order: `l.sort(key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)`

Comment: I was using a `lambda` solution until I learned `itemgetter()` is faster.

Answer (score 100):

Itemgetter lets you to sort by multiple criteria / columns:

```
sorted_list = sorted(list_to_sort, key=itemgetter(2,0,1))
```

Comment: I think this answer is very important. I think people trying to sort by inner array indexes will fall here but people looking to sort by MULTIPLE inner array indexes will start here and your answer helped me see that itemgetter will actually do that for you!

Answer (score 21):

multiple criteria can also be implemented through lambda function

```
sorted_list = sorted(list_to_sort, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```

Comment: What is the meaning of this lambda function above. Is it returning a tuple?

Answer (score 15):

```
array.sort(key = lambda x:x[1])
```

You can easily sort using this snippet, where 1 is the index of the element.

Answer (score 8):

Like this:

```
import operator
l = [...]
sorted_list = sorted(l, key=operator.itemgetter(desired_item_index))
```

Answer (score 8):

I think lambda function can solve your problem.

```
old_list = [[0,1,'f'], [4,2,'t'],[9,4,'afsd']]

#let's assume we want to sort lists by last value ( old_list[2] )
new_list = sorted(old_list, key=lambda x: x[2])

#Resulst of new_list will be:

[[9, 4, 'afsd'], [0, 1, 'f'], [4, 2, 't']]
```

Answer (score 2):

More easy to understand (What is Lambda actually doing):

```
ls2=[[0,1,'f'],[4,2,'t'],[9,4,'afsd']]
def thirdItem(ls):
    #return the third item of the list
    return ls[2]
#Sort according to what the thirdItem function return 
ls2.sort(key=thirdItem)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
**old_list = [[0,1,'f'], [4,2,'t'],[9,4,'afsd']]
    #let's assume we want to sort lists by last value ( old_list[2] )
    new_list = sorted(old_list, key=lambda x: x[2])**
```

correct me if i'm wrong but isnt the 'x[2]' calling the 3rd item in the list, not the 3rd item in the nested list? should it be x[2][2]?

Comment: No, because key/lambda is already iterating over the items in the first-level list.  x is a local variable bound to each item in turn.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting a Multidimensional Array [execute here][1]

```
points=[[2,1],[1,2],[3,5],[4,5],[3,1],[5,2],[3,8],[1,9],[1,3]]

def getKey(x):
   return [x[0],-x[1]]

points.sort(key=getKey)

print(points)
```

Comment: if you can explain the function getKey, that'd be great. from my Understanding ig, you're sorting according to the second sublist variable in descending order. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: sort method will sort the array in ascending order so when you pass first key as positive it'll sort in ascending and for second key it's -ve so we're altering sort to be in decreasing order for same elements

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you do not have any null or NaN values in the list you want to sort. If there are NaN values, then your sort will be off, impacting the sorting of the non-null values.

Check out [Python: sort function breaks in the presence of nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240050/python-sort-function-breaks-in-the-presence-of-nan)

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom key function you can easily sort any list of lists as you want:

```
L = [[0,1,'f'], [4,2,'t'], [9,4,'afsd']]

def sorter(lst):
    return lst[2].casefold()

L.sort(key=sorter)

# result: [[9, 4, 'afsd'], [0, 1, 'f'], [4, 2, 't']]
```