# joining all rows of a csv file that have the same first column with python

Tags: python

I realise similar has been posted before [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031832/joining-all-rows-of-a-csv-file-that-have-the-same-1st-column-value-in-python), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782655/joining-all-rows-of-a-csv-file-that-have-the-same-1st-column-value), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414562/python-joining-csv-files-where-key-is-first-column-value)

but I have tried these and they have not worked.

I have a single csv file with two columns similar to this:

```
james,phone1
james,phone2
james,phone3
paul,phone1
jackie,phone1
jackie,phone2
jackie,phone3
etc
```

I want to merge all the duplicates in column 1 using python to get something like:

```
james,phone1,phone2,phone3
paul,phone1
jackie,phone1,phone2,phone3
```

What would be the best way of doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
filename = "Filename.csv"
csvList = list(csv.reader(open(filename)))
csvDict = {}
for i in csvList :
    if i[0] in csvDict :
        csvDict[i[0]].append(i[1])
    else :
        csvDict[i[0]] = [i[1]]

print(csvDict)
```

use the dictionary to create the appropriate output format.

Comment: Glad to be helpful. Up-voting the answer and accepting the answer will be helpful for me.  :)