# Sort a list of lists by an item in the sublist

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of lists that contains users and scores as follows:

```
[["user1", 100], ["user2", 234], ["user3", 131]...]
```

I want to produce a list that sorts the users by score in declining order:

```
[["user2", 234], ["user3", 131], ["user1", 100]...]
```

How might I go about doing this kind of sort?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
>>> li = [["user1", 100], ["user2", 234], ["user3", 131]]
>>> 
>>> import operator
>>> 
>>> sorted(li, key=operator.itemgetter(1))   # Ascending order
[['user1', 100], ['user3', 131], ['user2', 234]]

>>> sorted(li, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)  # Reverse Sort
[['user2', 234], ['user3', 131], ['user1', 100]]
```

Answer (score 15):

You can custom the sort behaviour by pass a key and reverse. `sorted` will return a new list. If in-place sort wanted, use `list.sort`.

```
>>> a = [["user1", 100], ["user2", 234], ["user3", 131]]
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
[['user2', 234], ['user3', 131], ['user1', 100]]
```

Answer (score 7):

[sorted](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) accept optional `key` function and reverse parameter.

```
>>> sorted([["user1", 100], ["user2", 234], ["user3", 131]], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
[['user2', 234], ['user3', 131], ['user1', 100]]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
l = [["user1", 100], ["user2", 234], ["user3", 131]]
l.sort(lambda x, y: x[1])
```