# Sorting a list with sublists, based on whether the sublist has a designated string

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort a list in a way that the elements (sublists) which have a certain string (of my choosing) come first. I'd like to do this with the *key* parameter in Python's `sort()` method.

For example, if I have

#### Input

`l1 = [["hello", 1, 65, 331],["goodbye", 653, 43, 9], ["example", 22, 123, 92]]`

I'd like to use `l1.sort()` to sort the list in a way that, given "example" as the parameter, sorts the list like this:

#### Output

`[["example", 22, 123, 92], ["hello", 1, 65, 331], ["goodbye", 653, 43, 9]]`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: sort a list of lists by an item in the sublist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142090/python-sort-a-list-of-lists-by-an-item-in-the-sublist)

Comment: No, sorry, that's just lexicographic/alphanumeric ordering.

Comment: Can you give more explanations about the expected output?

Comment: If the string is they key for sorting, why is `h` before `g`?

Comment: The order of the sublists that don't contain "example" in them is completely irrelevant, what matters is that the first element(s) contain the given string.

Comment: `a certain string (of my choosing)`, could you give an example??

Comment: @Hasake - The accepted answer might be but the other answers show other ways, you should show what you've tried, aside from that, your `l1` isn't actually a valid list

Comment: `l1.sort(key=lambda sub: (sub[0]!='example', sub))`

Comment: @schwobaseggl You are a life-saver. How can I ever repay you? That's exactly what I'm looking for!!!

Comment: @Sayse Thanks for the input. I checked it out, you were right, but I still didn't know exactly how to tune it to work in my case. Why do you say it isn't a valid list?

Comment: @Hasake *Why do you say it isn't a valid list?* - the code you've posted has a superfluous `[` at the start of the list containing "goodbye"

Comment: @JonClements typo, my bad, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a lambda expression to check if the keyword is in the sublist, this will return a boolean truth value for each expression in which `False` will be ordered before `True`, so we also apply reverse so that those that were `True` come first. it will maintain the order of the sub list after ordering by `True` and `False`. So those sublists with the same truth value will stay in the order they were in.

```py
l1 = [["hello", 1, 65, 331],["goodbye", 653, 43, 9], ["example", 22, 123, 92]]
keyword = "example"
print(l1)
l1.sort(key=lambda sublist: keyword in sublist, reverse=True)
print(l1)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[['hello', 1, 65, 331], ['goodbye', 653, 43, 9], ['example', 22, 123, 92]]
[['example', 22, 123, 92], ['hello', 1, 65, 331], ['goodbye', 653, 43, 9]]
```

Comment: Thank you! How did you get to this? This was my first approach, I tried for a long while to use boolean values inside lambda which was the more logical approach for me as well. However, I kept getting an error telling me something like "bool not allowed in lambda" or whatnot, so I discarded it. Turns out it works so thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Say you want `goodbye` to come first, you could do:

```
l1 = [["hello", 1, 65, 331],["goodbye", 653, 43, 9], ["example", 22, 123, 92]]

s = 'goodbye'
sorted(l1, key=lambda x: x[0]!=s)
# [['goodbye', 653, 43, 9], ['hello', 1, 65, 331], ['example', 22, 123, 92]]
```

---

For a detailed exaplanation on how the above works, check this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53947928/force-items-at-beginning-and-end-of-list/53947953#53947953)

Comment: or `s not in x` do don't rely on location inside the sublist

Comment: Well from the example it seems that the position where the string is is known. If that is the case this will be much more efficient @Tomerikoo

Comment: @yatu, this is was exactly what I wanted. Given that the string position is known this really is the best way. Thank you!!

Comment: `l1.sort(key=lambda x: not any([i in x for i in ["goodbye", "example"]]))`

Comment: @tpk thank you for the input. However, I was looking forward to using this technique in a list of lists with far more options than just these 3. Given that, it'd be far too much of a hassle to negate all of them, but at least I learned something new. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code. Excuse me for putting it this long but it serves the purpose :)

```
import operator
def sortfunction(parameter,list):
    tmplist1 = []
    tmplist2 = []
    for elem in list:
        if elem[0] == parameter:
            tmplist1 = elem
        else:
            tmplist2.append(elem)
    sorted_temp = sorted(tmplist2, key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
    final_list = tmplist1 + sorted_temp
    return final_list

#Call the function:
sortfunction("example",l1)
```

**Output:**

```
['example', 22, 123, 92, ['goodbye', 653, 43, 9], ['hello', 1, 65, 331]]
```

Comment: Thank you! No worries regarding length. Even though I was looking for a one-liner, this show's me how to actually use `operator.itemgetter()` properly, which is great! But at the core of the question, yes, I could definitely get around by using this! Again, thanks for the input.

Comment: @Hasake Cheers!