# Python: How to sort a list of lists by the most common first element?

Tags: python, list, sorting

How do you sort a list of lists by the count of the first element? For example, if I had the following list below, I'd want the list to be sorted so that all the 'University of Georgia' entries come first, then the 'University of Michigan' entries, and then the 'University of Florida' entry.

```
l = [['University of Michigan','James Jones','phd'],
     ['University of Georgia','Anne   Greene','ba'],
     ['University of Michigan','Frank Kimball','ma'],
     ['University of Florida','Nate Franklin','ms'],
     ['University of Georgia','Sara Dean','ms'],
     ['University of Georgia','Beth Johnson','bs']]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(item[0] for item in l)
print sorted(l, key = lambda x: -c[x[0]])
```

**Output**

```
[['University of Georgia', 'Anne   Greene', 'ba'],
 ['University of Georgia', 'Sara Dean', 'ms'],
 ['University of Georgia', 'Beth Johnson', 'bs'],
 ['University of Michigan', 'James Jones', 'phd'],
 ['University of Michigan', 'Frank Kimball', 'ma'],
 ['University of Florida', 'Nate Franklin', 'ms']]
```

Vanilla dict version:

```
c = {}
for item in l:
    c[item[0]] = c.get(item[0], 0) + 1
print sorted(l, key = lambda x: -c[x[0]])
```

`defaultdict` version:

```
from collections import defaultdict
c = defaultdict(int)
for item in l:
    c[item[0]] += 1
print sorted(l, key = lambda x: -c[x[0]])
```

Comment: @zhangxaochen You are welcome :) You are good at numpy yourself :)

Comment: Do not forget that Counter does not exist in Python 2.6.6 so that this cannot be used if a later Python is not available.

Comment: @sabbahillel Thanks :) Please check the plain dict version :)

Comment: another way for the last version is with a `defaultdict`

Comment: @AdamCushner Please check my answer. Included that as well :)

Answer (score -1):

Getting solution from here: [How to sort a list of lists by a specific index of the inner list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174941/how-to-sort-a-list-of-lists-by-a-specific-index-of-the-inner-list)

```
from operator import itemgetter

L=[['University of Michigan','James Jones','phd'],['University of Georgia','Anne   Greene','ba'],['University of Michigan','Frank Kimball','ma'],['University of Florida','Nate Franklin','ms'],['University of Georgia','Sara Dean','ms'],['University of Georgia','Beth Johnson','bs']]

print 'Before:', L
print ' After:', sorted(L, key=itemgetter(0))
```

Output

```
Before: [['University of Michigan', 'James Jones', 'phd'], ['University of Georgia', 'Anne   Greene', 'ba'], ['University of Michigan', 'Frank Kimball', 'ma'], ['University of Florida', 'Nate Franklin', 'ms'], ['University of Georgia', 'Sara Dean', 'ms'], ['University of Georgia', 'Beth Johnson', 'bs']]
 After: [['University of Florida', 'Nate Franklin', 'ms'], ['University of Georgia', 'Anne   Greene', 'ba'], ['University of Georgia', 'Sara Dean', 'ms'], ['University of Georgia', 'Beth Johnson', 'bs'], ['University of Michigan', 'James Jones', 'phd'], ['University of Michigan', 'Frank Kimball', 'ma']]
```