# How to numerically sort string in list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list inside of a list, and the inner list has strings of numbers (float) and words. 
What I need to sort the list by, is in position list[0]. So for example,

```
list = [['8.34', 'a'],['3.55', 'c'],['5.92', 'b']]
```

I'm trying to sort the list numerically to look like

```
list = [['3.55', 'c'],['5.92', 'b'],['8.34', 'a']]
```

I've tried

```
sorted(list, key = float)
```

but I get an error message: 'float() argument must be a string or a number' and I've tried using lambda as well. Neither works. Could someone help please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a list of lists by a specific index of the inner list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174941/how-to-sort-a-list-of-lists-by-a-specific-index-of-the-inner-list)

Comment: `list` is a python type, using it as a variable name will override current type.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it to work...apparently all that I needed to do was my_List.sort() ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try passing a `lambda` function.:

```
sorted(my_list, key = lambda x : float(x[0]))
```

`x` will be an element of the list (which is also a list, because `my_list` is a list of lists), and `float(x[0])` will return the float representation of the *first* element of that list.

**Demo:**

```
>>> my_list = [['8.34', 'a'],['3.55', 'c'],['5.92', 'b']]
>>> print sorted(my_list, key = lambda x : float(x[0]))
[['3.55', 'c'], ['5.92', 'b'], ['8.34', 'a']]
```

**Note:**

- Don't use `list` as the name of a variable, because you will hide its built-in implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Your list contains lists, so you cannot use `float` directly. You need to use a function that returns float value of the first item in each list.

```
>>> lis = [['8.34', 'a'],['3.55', 'c'],['5.92', 'b']]
>>> lis.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[0]))
>>> lis
[['3.55', 'c'], ['5.92', 'b'], ['8.34', 'a']]
```

Comment: I get 'could not convert string to float:' error message

Comment: builtins.ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: @jenncar That means one of the items in your list cannot be converted to `float`. What exactly does your list contain?

Comment: I just realized some of the inner lists have an empty string in position [0]

Comment: Sorry, I should have caught this earlier.

Comment: @jenncar How do you want to handle those empty strings?

Answer (score -2):

This earlier answer can be used in your case also:
[How to sort a list of lists by a specific index of the inner list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174941/how-to-sort-a-list-of-lists-by-a-specific-index-of-the-inner-list)

```
from operator import itemgetter
list = [['8.34', 'a'],['3.55', 'c'],['5.92', 'b']]
print sorted(list, key=itemgetter(0))
```

gives the desired output:

```
[['3.55', 'c'], ['5.92', 'b'], ['8.34', 'a']]
```

Comment: You are comparing strings not float.

Comment: `list` is a python type, using it as a variable name will override current type.