# Sorting a complex structure of array of array

Tags: python, arrays

I am looking for a way to sort my array of array which has a complex structure :

```
L=[[
[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],1,56],
[[6,6,6,6,6,6,6],1,3],
[[3,3,3,3,3,3,3],1,54]],
[[[2,2,2,2,2,2,2],2,42],
[[5,5,5,5,5,5,5],2,6]]]
```

I woul'd like to sort it by the last elements meaning (56, 3, 54 and 42, 6).
What I want to get it is that :

```
L=[[
[[6,6,6,6,6,6,6],1,3],
[[3,3,3,3,3,3,3],1,54],
[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],1,56]],
[[[5,5,5,5,5,5,5],2,6],
[[2,2,2,2,2,2,2],2,42]]]
```

I have already tried : `L.sort(key=lambda x: x[0][0][2])`
but it doesn't work...

I have seen those advices but I haven't succeeded in making it work :

[How to sort a list of lists by a specific index of the inner list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174941/how-to-sort-a-list-of-lists-by-a-specific-index-of-the-inner-list)

Any help would be appreciated !
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itemgetter` to sort multiple index.
In this case, sort index **1** and then index **2** on `L[i]`

```
import operator
for i in range(len(L)):
    L[i] = sorted(L[i], key=operator.itemgetter(1, 2))
```

or simpler:

```
import operator
    for s in L:
        s.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1, 2))
```

*thanks to @georg*

output:

```
[[[[6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6], 1, 3],
  [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 1, 54],
  [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 1, 56]],
 [[[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], 2, 6], 
  [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 2, 42]]]
```

Comment: You can simplify this: `for s in L: s.sort(...)`. No need for indexes - lists are references!

Comment: No, `s = sorted(s)` won't work! `s.sort()` is crucial.

Comment: I'm confused. Why `s=sorted(s)` won't work, while my original answer `L[i] = sorted(L[i])` works?

Comment: Because `L[i]=...` modifies the value of `L` itself, while `s=...` just assigns a new value to `s`.

Comment: Thanks @georg, I modified my answer again!