# Sort two lists of lists by index of inner list

Tags: python, list, sorting, numpy

Assume I want to sort a list of lists like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174941/how-to-sort-a-list-of-lists-by-a-specific-index-of-the-inner-list):

```
>>>L=[[0, 1, 'f'], [4, 2, 't'], [9, 4, 'afsd']]
>>>sorted(L, key=itemgetter(2))
[[9, 4, 'afsd'], [0, 1, 'f'], [4, 2, 't']]
```

(Or with lambda.) Now I have a second list which I want to sort in the same order, so I need the **new order of the indices**. sorted() or .sort() do not return indices. How can I do that?

Actually in my case both lists contain **numpy arrays**. But the numpy sort/argsort aren't intuitive for that case either.

Comment: what is the desired output _finally_?

Comment: I'd say the first step would be to give us a complete example. I don't see a second list. And I don't see numpy, either.

Comment: So based on the shifting performed on the first `list`, order a second one? If yes, `zip` them before ordering.

Comment: Could you show your second list and the expected output, to make this clearer? If your second list was `[1,2,3]`, you want to sort it as `[3,1,2]`, right?

Comment: Perhaps: [Sorting list based on values from another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list)

Comment: You could e.g. either sort the enumeration of the list to get the new order of the indices, or sort the zipped lists and then unzip.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you want to order `B` in the example below, based on a sorting rule you apply on `L`. Take a look at this:

```
L = [[0, 1, 'f'], [4, 2, 't'], [9, 4, 'afsd']]
B = ['a', 'b', 'c']

result = [i for _, i in sorted(zip(L, B), key=lambda x: x[0][2])]
print(result)  # ['c', 'a', 'b']
# that corresponds to [[9, 4, 'afsd'], [0, 1, 'f'], [4, 2, 't']]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to know how the list has been rearranged. i.e. where is the 0th element after sorting, etc.

If so, you are one step away:

```
L2 = [L.index(x) for x in sorted(L, key=itemgetter(2))]
```

which gives:

```
[2, 0, 1]
```

As tobias points out, this is needlessly complex compared to

```
map(itemgetter(0),  sorted(enumerate(L), key=lambda x: x[1][2]))
```

Comment: For longer lists, this is very wasteful, having O(n²) complexity. Better use `sorted(enumerate(...))`

Answer (score 0):

## NumPy

Setup:

```
import numpy as np
L = np.array([[0, 1, 'f'], [4, 2, 't'], [9, 4, 'afsd']])
S = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Solution:

```
print S[L[:,2].argsort()]
```

Output:

```
['c' 'a' 'b']
```

## Just Python

You could combine both lists, sort them together, and separate them again.

```
>>> L = [[0, 1, 'f'], [4, 2, 't'], [9, 4, 'afsd']]
>>> S = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> L, S = zip(*sorted(zip(L, S), key=lambda x: x[0][2]))
>>> L
([9, 4, 'afsd'], [0, 1, 'f'], [4, 2, 't'])
>>> S
('c', 'a', 'b')
```

I guess you could do something similar in NumPy as well...