# Python - 2D array sort by date & time

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

I have the following two dimensional array:

```
arr = [
["A", "B", "C", "10.03.2030", "14:06"],
["W", "R", "Q", "09.04.2025", "12:06"],
["Y", "X", "V", "11.05.2022", "12:06"],
["Z", "N", "H", "10.03.2030", "14:06"],
]
```

I want to sort the array by & time, is there a fast way to do that in python?

thanks in advance

andy

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was actually wrong. But to answer your question about being downvoted: I didn't downvote (not did I upvote) your question, but those who did likely did so because 1) you haven't shown any effort at accomplishing this yourself and 2) this is not a new problem and could easily be solved with some effort Googling. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort by first transforming the dates into ISO8601 format  (as opposed to transforming to actual dates with `datetime.strptime` which is pretty slow) and then break ties using the already standardised time string:

```
lst = sorted(arr, key=lambda x: (x[3].split('.')[::-1], x[-1]))
print(lst)
```

`x[3].split('.')[::-1]` builds a list of the ISO date from the original date string, bringing the year first, month next and then date.

---

```
[['Y', 'X', 'V', '11.05.2022', '12:06'],
 ['W', 'R', 'Q', '09.04.2025', '12:06'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', '10.03.2030', '14:06'],
 ['Z', 'N', 'H', '10.03.2030', '14:06']]
```

Comment: thank you so much, your answer was the best, for date and time, all other solutions sort only by date and not the time too. I want to ask you something, can you please explain this part: (x[3].split('.')[::-1], x[-1], this will take the date and split it by (dot), for first one  ['2022', '05', '11'] and I dont understand why negative number -1 and not 2 ? and also the x[-1] Please...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174941/how-to-sort-a-list-of-lists-by-a-specific-index-of-the-inner-list), you should use [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for this purpose.

To sort your data by time, use this:

```
from operator import itemgetter
print(sorted(arr, key=itemgetter(4)))
[['W', 'R', 'Q', '09.04.2025', '12:06'], 
['Y', 'X', 'V', '11.05.2022', '12:06'], 
['A', 'B', 'C', '10.03.2030', '14:06'], 
['Z', 'N', 'H', '10.03.2030', '14:06']]
```

If you need to sort by date (year), you need to define a separate function or use a lamda. I have written both solutions:

```
def sorting(item):
    return item[3].split('.')[2]

print(sorted(arr, key=sorting))

# using lambda
print(sorted(arr, key= lambda item:item[3].split('.')[2]))

[['Y', 'X', 'V', '11.05.2022', '12:06'], 
['W', 'R', 'Q', '09.04.2025', '12:06'], 
['A', 'B', 'C', '10.03.2030', '14:06'], 
['Z', 'N', 'H', '10.03.2030', '14:06']]
```

This way you don't rely on a third party package import.

Comment: But this doesn't sort the date properly. Year 2025 is first, 2030 is in-between, and 2022 is last.

Comment: @Mark I just updated my code to sort by the list by year.

Answer (score 0):

very short and neat code than others given above

```
lst = sorted(arr, key=lambda x: (x[3].split('.')[::-1], x[-1]))
```

Comment: Besides not sorting by time, this isn't any different than Moses Koledoye's answer...

Comment: this is not sorting by time, its only by date.