# I am wondering if there is a way to use the sorted() function to sort by a specified index in a 2-d or even 3-d array

Tags: python, sorting, multidimensional-array

I created a 3-d array for storing info for a bowling team. I've organized it in my head as a directory with teams in it and those teams have profiles in them and the profiles include player name, team number, and score.

I created a test list to use:

```
test = [
    [["John",1,153],["Lizzy",1,129],["Matt",1,178]],
    [["Jorge",2,156],["Brent",2,145],["Kyle",2,207]],
    [["Chuck",3,300]],
    [["Joey",4,230],["Stanley",4,60]]
]
```

I want to create a sorted list of all the profiles by their score, and also another list by name alphabetically. I could do this with for loops but it would look a lot nicer just using the `sorted()`. Is there a way to use the key parameter in the `sorted()` function to do this?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: You should use `numpy` if you want arrays. That's a nested `list`, and it's tedious to sort it the way you want.

Comment: @gmds what's tedious about `sorted`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It seems tedious to sort all three levels in that way, each with their own key function. I could be wrong!

Comment: the expected output is to have all the profiles sorted by score, which i realized that it would essentially just break apart all the teams so what I did was write all the profiles into a new list and then sort that list using sorted(), with the key parameter as a function to select the 3rd index. here's what it looked like

Comment: `def sort_score(directory):
    sorted_score = []
    for team in directory:
        for profile in team:
            sorted_score.append(profile)
    sorted_score = sorted(sorted_score,key=takeScore,reverse=True)
    return sorted_score

def takeScore(elem):
    return elem[2]`

Comment: side question: how do I show code in a comment and have it format correctly?

Comment: If you found an answer to your own question, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

here's what I ended up doing

```
def sort_score(directory):
    sorted_score = []
    for team in directory:
        for profile in team:
            sorted_score.append(profile)
    sorted_score = sorted(sorted_score,key=takeScore,reverse=True)
    return sorted_score

def takeScore(elem):
    return elem[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do two things: [flatten the list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/5079316) and [sort the result by a specific index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174941/how-to-sort-a-list-of-lists-by-a-specific-index-of-the-inner-list).

```
from operator import itemgetter

test = [
    [["John",1,153],["Lizzy",1,129],["Matt",1,178]],
    [["Jorge",2,156],["Brent",2,145],["Kyle",2,207]],
    [["Chuck",3,300]],
    [["Joey",4,230],["Stanley",4,60]]
]

sorted_by_name = sorted([p for team in test for p in team], key=itemgetter(0))

sorted_by_score = sorted([p for team in test for p in team], key=itemgetter(2))
```