# Python sort list of DataFrames on first column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of DataFrames where I am outputting just the column names for each. I am able to sort each DataFrame by column name, but I also want to sort the list itself based on the name of the first column in each DataFrame. I've searched around but can't find what the appropriate key for `sorted()` would be.

```py
for df in df_list:
        df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)

sorted_dflist = sorted(df_list, key = ???)

My Output: 
( 3  4  5  8 11 12)( 7 10)( 1  6  9 13 14)(2)

Expected Output: 
( 1  6  9 13 14)(2)( 3  4  5  8 11 12)( 7 10)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a list of lists by a specific index of the inner list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174941/how-to-sort-a-list-of-lists-by-a-specific-index-of-the-inner-list)

Answer (score 2):

As I understood, the sort criterion is the first element in the first
column of each DataFrame. To sort this way, try the following code:

```
sorted_dflist = sorted(df_list, key = lambda x: x.iloc[0,0])
```

To sort by the **name** of the first column, run:

```
sorted_dflist = sorted(df_list, key = lambda x: x.columns[0])
```

Comment: Edited above. It should be sorted by the name of the first column in each DataFrame.