# How to split a list based on tuple content in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of 3-tuples, and I want to split them on the last coordinate. So for example if the input were:

> [(1,2,x), (2,3,x), (1,2,z), (2,20,z)]

I'd want the output to be

> [(1,2,x),(2,3,x)],[(1,2,z),(2,20,z)]

My current approach involves getting all N distinct 3rd indices and looping over the list N times to build the list of lists. I am wondering if there is a pythonic way to do this without looping multiple times.

Comment: I suppose this should be a 2D array instead of 1D?

Comment: nested list comprehension `third_indices = ['x','z']`
`[[a1 for a1 in a if a1[-1]==ix] for ix in third_indices]` might be a bit better (`a`is your list)

Comment: Its a 1D List filled with tuples of dimension 3.

Comment: Your example has the elements already ordered by the third element. Is that always the case? Is this possible: `[(1,2,'x'), (2,3,'x'), (1,2,'z'), (2,20,'z'), (3,4,'x')]` if so, what is the result?

Comment: @Mark No, there's no condition on grouping, and I don't know how many distinct 3rd elements there are apriori. The result on your example is [(1,2,x), (2,3,x), (3,4,x)], [(1,2,z),(2,20,z)]

Comment: The result is: [(1,2,x), (2,3,x), (3,4,x)], [(1,2,z),(2,20,z)]. That's two groups -- one list for each third element (in this case x and z).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way with complexity of O(n):

```
lt = [(1,2,'x'), (2,3,'x'), (1,2,'z'), (2,20,'z')]

res = {}
for i in lt:
  res.setdefault(i[2], []).append(i)

print(list(res.values()))
```

output:

```
>>>
[[(1, 2, 'x'), (2, 3, 'x')], [(1, 2, 'z'), (2, 20, 'z')]]
```

Comment: This solution seems to be the best. Is there a way to post-sort the lists based on the third tuple term?

Comment: Nvm solved, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174941/how-to-sort-a-list-of-lists-by-a-specific-index-of-the-inner-list

Answer (score 1):

nested list comprehension
if you dont know `third_indices`a priori:

```
my_list = [(1,2,'x'), (2,3,'x'), (1,2,'z'), (2,20,'z')]
third_indices = set([ix[-1] for ix in my_list])
[[item for item in my_list if item[-1]==ix] for ix in third_indices]
```

Comment: This works thanks! Is there a way to sort the final result based on the third tuple elements, i.e. have the 'x' list appear before the 'z' list.

Comment: @GTOgod this is complexity of O(n2) which is not optimal

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @eshirvana, but using defaultdict, which is very performant and common for this type of problem. I would make a defaultdict and save lists of tuples based the key determined by the last element. Then all your groups will be in the `values()`

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [(1,2,'x'), (2,3,'x'), (1,2,'z'), (2,20,'z'), (3,4,'x')]

groups = defaultdict(list)

for t in l:
    groups[t[-1]].append(t)
    
list(groups.values())
# [[(1, 2, 'x'), (2, 3, 'x'), (3, 4, 'x')], [(1, 2, 'z'), (2, 20, 'z')]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
my_list = [(1,2,x), (2,3,x), (1,2,z), (2,20,z)]

list_x = [item for item in my_list if item[2] == x]
list_y = [item for item in my_list if item[2] == y]
list_z = [item for item in my_list if item[2] == z]
```

Edit: If x,y and z are not numbers then this should work:

```
my_list = [(1,2,'x'), (2,3,'x'), (1,2,'z'), (2,20,'z')]

list_x = [item for item in my_list if item[2] == 'x']
list_y = [item for item in my_list if item[2] == 'y']
list_z = [item for item in my_list if item[2] == 'z']
```

If you want them in the same list then do this

```
final_list = list((list_x,list_z))
```

Comment: This doesn't work because I don't know the contents of the 3rd tuple apriori

Comment: So its not an integer? I was expecting it to be a number.