# How do I sort a list of lists in python?

Tags: python

How would I make this code:

```
[['Phil', 19], ['Billy', 8221], ['Jerald', 1], ['Bobby', 194]]
```

Sorted by number into this code:

```
[['Billy', 8221], ['Bobby', 194], ['Phil', 19], ['Jerald', 1]]
```

I tried searching Google but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: I know the code blocks are a bit wierd just ignore that

Comment: Duplicate of [How to sort a list of lists by a specific index of the inner list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174941/how-to-sort-a-list-of-lists-by-a-specific-index-of-the-inner-list)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Answer (score 3):

Define a list of name-age pairs

```
pairs = [['Phil', 19], ['Billy', 8221], ['Jerald', 1], ['Bobby', 194]]
```

Sort the data by the second element (age) in descending order

```
sorted_pairs = sorted(pairs, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Print the sorted data

```
print(sorted_data)
```